# How do I investigate "Snippet type is unrecognized" when viewing contact record

Tags: core

when trying to view the contacts summary page, the error "Snippet type is unrecognized" is displayed in the usual yellow strip accross the screen.

I can't see any differences between this contact and any other contacts (which do display) (apart from the obvious).

ConfigAndLog doesn't provide much of use (for me - sorry):

> _Apr 01 11:12:09  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
>   (
>       [message] => Snippet type  is unrecognized
>       [code] => 
>   )
>
> Apr 01 11:12:09  [info] $backTrace = #0
>   /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(364):
>   CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
>
> ## 1 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Region.php(223):
>
> CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Snippet type  is unrecognized")
>
> ## 2 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/block.crmRegion.php(26):
>
> CRM_Core_Region->render("                \n              ...", TRUE)
>
> ## 3 /var/sites/praxisunico.org.uk/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/en_GB/%%12/12B/12B53F83%%Summary.tpl.php(182):
>
> smarty_block_crmRegion((Array:1), "                \n              ...",
>   Object(CRM_Core_Smarty), FALSE)
>
> ## 4 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1907):
>
> include("/var/sites/praxisunico.org.uk/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/en_GB/%%12/12B/...")
>
> ## 5 /var/sites/praxisunico.org.uk/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/en_GB/%%0C/0CB/0CBEC124%%default.tpl.php(19):
>
> Smarty->_smarty_include((Array:2))
>
> ## 6 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1907):
>
> include("/var/sites/praxisunico.org.uk/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/en_GB/%%0C/0CB/...")
>
> ## 7 /var/sites/praxisunico.org.uk/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/en_GB/%%06/069/0693F89E%%drupal.tpl.php(64):
>
> Smarty->_smarty_include((Array:2))
>
> ## 8 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1264):
>
> include("/var/sites/praxisunico.org.uk/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/en_GB/%%06/069/...")
>
> ## 9 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(203):
>
> Smarty->fetch("CRM/common/drupal.tpl", NULL, NULL, FALSE)
>
> ## 10 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(233):
>
> CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch("CRM/common/drupal.tpl")
>
> ## 11 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(103):
>
> CRM_Core_Page->run()
>
> ## 12 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312):
>
> CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run((Array:3), NULL)
>
> ## 13 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86):
>
> CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
>
> ## 14 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54):
>
> CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
>
> ## 15 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489):
>
> CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
>
> ## 16 internal function: civicrm_invoke("contact", "view")
>
> ## 17 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
>
> ## 18 /var/www/drupal743civi4610/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
>
> ## 19 {main}
>
> _

Anyone know what this may relate to or where to look for clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try deleting the contents of `sites/xxx/files/civicrm/templates_c`